# Why is my C++ program killed by OS

Tags: process, signals, c++

I've compiled small C++ application for school project on my virtual ubuntu 11.04. However when I attempt to run it over some larger data set after ~20 sec  the program is killed by OS.

> Killed (SIGKILL)

I need to find out why and remove the problem. Could it be that I've not enough memory to run the program?
Note: I need to find data set large enough to make it run for several minutes.

Comment: Strange, when you request resources like memory or IO operation, the OS will say "OK" or "not OK", but killing the process seems a little drastic. What could have happened is that you were killed because you performed an invalid operation (accessing memory you can't access). Do you have BUS ERROR/Segmentation Fault errors? Run your program within gdb (gdb ./program and hit 'r [arg1] [arg2] to run it), provide us with the output.

Comment: How large is large? Also, what `ulimit`s is it running under? Type `ulimit` on the same console you're running your program from to see if the environment is severely limiting some resource you might need (e.g. memory, CPU time, etc).

Comment: Can you share the code? Or at least the part of the code where it happens (you can build it with debug information and run it under some debugger like `gdb` — when it gets killed, you should be able to get a backtrace (although I'm not sure about how `gdb` handles `SIGKILL`, I know `SIGSEGV` can be trapped by `gdb`, now `SIGKILL` I don't know.)

Comment: Also check `dmesg`, might be some info there.

Comment: gdb just prints `Program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed. The program no longer exists` When I use smaller input data set, the program works fine.

Comment: It seems there is not enough memory for such data set dmsg: Out of memory: kill process 1666 (gnome-session) score 221113 or a child

Comment: @aki - Often resources are allocated on the assumption that they will be available when required. Many OSes overallocate on this assumption.

Comment: I've found one memory leak in the code using valgrind. Now it works much better.

Comment: @ChrisDown: indeed, I forgot that Linux overcommits memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably killed by kernel's [oom killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer). `dmesg` should contain information about it. Sorry, but you may need to redesign your algorithm.

Comment: Would the OOM killer kill this application? Isn't it designed to select a program with a half-random algorithm and kill it? ahh.. I really despise the OOM killer, I understand why it's needed though... Wish one could build a linux kernel with a -DLOGICAL_BEHAVIOR flag :).

Comment: It tries to kill most memory-hungry application. In some cases (due to memory sharing) it can kill wrong application, but most of the time it does the right thing.

Comment: Oh it evolved well since the time it used to kill sshd.

Comment: You can disable the OOM killer if you really like to. But then you are no longer able to over-allocate memory.